# Reactjs : Routing to another layout from button action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React-router-dom V5 ,

Within my component , while rendering i ve to display a button , which would redirect me to another component layout :

i ve put this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DashboardLayout from "../../views-layouts/DashboardLayout";
import { BrowserRouter , Switch ,Route , Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class WelcomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    const heroStyles = {
      padding: '50px 0 70px'
    };

    const history = useHistory();

    function handleClick() {
      history.push("/home");
    }

    return (
      <div>
        WELCOME
        <span />
        <BrowserRouter>

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' component={DashboardLayout} />
          <button type="button">
            <Link to="/home">Click to login</Link>
          </button>      
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default WelcomePage;
```

But i ve had this error

```
×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: remove this code ` const history = useHistory();` its a hook and can be used only in functional component . But what you have here is a class component . And also remove your `handleClick()` function .

Comment: thanks a lotf that goes fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a hook in a class component.  They are only able to run in functional components.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error, hooks can only be called from functional react components or other custom hooks ([Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)). This is true for all hooks i.e. built-in react hooks (like useState, useEffect), custom hooks or hooks provided by third party packages

"useHistory" is a hook provided by "react-router-dom" package and you are calling it from a class component.

There is a alternative given for class components in React router documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

In "DashboardLayout" component props, you can find "history" prop.
You can use following:

```
this.props.history.push("/home");
```

instead of

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push("/home");
```

As you are passing "DashboardLayout" as a component prop in "Route", you will get history prop in "DashboardLayout" component.

If "history" prop is not present in a particular component, then you can get it by wrapping that component with "withRouter" HOC.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter